# Capturing different streams in file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to capture the `Verbose`, `Error` and other streams of a PowerShell script in a file. This to monitor the output of my script.

The following code works fine:

```
$LogFile    = 'S:\ScriptLog.log'
$ScriptFile = 'S:\TestieScript.ps1'

powershell -Command $ScriptFile *>&1 > $LogFile
```

However, the moment I try to put a space in one of the file paths, it's no longer working. I tried a lot of things, like double quotes, single quotes, .. but no luck.

To illustrate, the following code doesn't work:

```
$LogFile    = 'S:\ScriptLog.log'
$ScriptFile = 'S:\Testie Script.ps1'

powershell -Command $ScriptFile *>&1 > $LogFile
```

One person in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784382/how-to-redirect-powershell-output-when-run-from-task-scheduler) has the same issue.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to run a file whose name contains a space as a command without proper quoting, so you're most likely getting an error like this in your log:

> The term 'S:\Testie' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Either add proper quoting (and the call operator `&`, because your path is now a string):

```
powershell -Command "& '$ScriptFile'" *>&1 > $LogFile
```

or (better) use the `-File` parameter, as [@CB.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32093081/1630171) already suggested:

```
powershell -File $ScriptFile *>&1 > $LogFile
```

which has the additional advantage that the call will return the actual exit code of the script.

**Edit:** If you want to run the command as a scheduled task you'll need to use something like this:

```
powershell -Command "& 'S:\Testie Script.ps1' *>&1 > 'S:\ScriptLog.log'; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
```

because the redirection operators only work *inside* a PowerShell process.

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, this works flawlessly in the ISE. I'm now trying to put this in a Scheduled task as following: `Program: Powershell` and `Arguments: -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "S:\Testie Script.ps1" *>&1 > "S:\ScriptLog.log"`. But this doesn't even generate a file..

Answer (score 2):

try using `-file` parameter:

```
powershell -file $ScriptFile *>&1 > $LogFile
```